Warning: Undefined array key "resident_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\domiciliaryNexus\pages\residents.php on line 96" same on line 97
<?php

            // error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING);
            $query = "SELECT resident_id, fname, mname, lname, sex, bday, educ, occupation, citizenship, religion, contact_no, civil_status, house_no, street FROM resident";

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $i = 0;
                define("BDAY_POS", 5);
                define("AGE_POS", 6);
                define("N_DB_FIELDS", 14);
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for ($i = 0; $i < N_DB_FIELDS; $i++) {
                        if ($i == BDAY_POS) {
                            $bday = $row[$i];
                            $col = convert_to_long_date($row[$i], null);
                            echo "<td>$col</td>";
                        } else if ($i == AGE_POS) {
                            $inner_query = "CALL calculate_age(?, @age)";
                            $inner_stmt = $pdo->prepare($inner_query);
                            $inner_stmt->execute([$bday]);

                            $inner_query = "SELECT @age";
                            $inner_stmt = $pdo->prepare($inner_query);
                            $inner_stmt->execute();
                            $col = $inner_stmt->fetchColumn();
                            echo "<td>$col</td>";
                            echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit-resident" data-resident-id="' . $row['resident_id'] . '">Edit</button></td>';
                    echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-resident" data-resident-id="' . $row['resident_id'] . '">Delete</button></td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
            ?>

I'm new to programming, I struggle to figure out what's wrong with the way I use $row['resident_id'].
At first I was using
SELECT * FROM resident;
Then I changed it to
SELECT resident_id, fname, mname, lname, sex, bday, educ, occupation, citizenship, religion, contact_no, civil_status, house_no, street FROM resident; 
Hoping it will miraculously fix the problem. lol.
I cant proceed in creating edit and delete function.
